# How we can Create Wallet / Generate address in polkadot

Tags: account, python

I want to Create Wallet / Generate address like in ethereum we use web3.py but how could I do same thing in polkadot by using python?

Comment: Could you select an answer if any one of them answers your question?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the chain.

Most of the chains are using SR25519.

Check https://github.com/polkascan/py-sr25519-bindings.

Example:

```python
# you need to install py-sr25519-bindings first.

import sr25519
from random import randbytes

message = b"test"

raw_seed = randbytes(32)
public_key, private_key = sr25519.pair_from_seed(raw_seed)

print(f'Raw seed: {raw_seed.hex()}')
print(f'Public Key: {public_key.hex()}')
print(f'Private Key: {private_key.hex()}')

# Generate signature
signature = sr25519.sign(
    (public_key, private_key),
    message
)

print('Signature', signature.hex())

# Verify message with signature
if sr25519.verify(signature, message, public_key):
    print('Verified')
```

```
Raw seed: 2a6cdceb2fc16b07b60cec685bfe171c1d0b989e962dbf41f0e044060de2aa54
Public Key: c20c0de890c5a809a9837b439e1e7c86bb23e31932e367b66d14a82d5f429c6e
Private Key: 189c98cd0c669869df80dead8d310a8430f8e35705036f41a79555dc513a7509ee96d314905deb7dbb1f0830343694756c10e812124201d7bd44530874b6b4b9
Signature c64d79859ef905184556f87663e1b8a22eda672328f0973d293aaf379bbc5a1e074572ff2245837a04217603a5316eeaf504bbda7b4427c0393dfe7d57020c87
Verified
```

---

Some chains like Moonbeam, use ECDSA. So, web3.py works for them.

Comment: I want to create a wallet on polkadot

Comment: Polkadot uses SR25519. So, https://github.com/polkascan/py-sr25519-bindings is the Python library for creating a wallet on Polkadot.

Comment: can you further elaborate it how could I create a wallet by using this library if possible it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I made a mistake here. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Alright I'm waiting

Comment: Updated. Please take a look.

Comment: when I've posted the public key: c20c0de890c5a809a9837b439e1e7c86bb23e31932e367b66d14a82d5f429c6e on polkascan and westendscan it's not showing

Comment: You don't have DOT. So the account won't be created. But it's a valid address. You just need to transfer some token to it, then it will appear on Polkascan.

Comment: do we need to create a different address for westend?

Comment: I've seen a address on polkascan "15XDJ467QETozXzSa5isHUmBAUNoiy8bCkqDKVkZ77wFdyux" it has 0 DOTS but still I can see it on polkascan

Comment: If you want more safety, use a different key. In technical, Westend uses SR25519 too.
For the second question, I won't answer you here. This comment is too long (also, off-topic). You could create an account on PolkadotApps (the official wallet) and see if it appears on the Polkascan.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface for that, it has a lot of helper functions to interface with Substrate:

```python
from substrateinterface import Keypair
keypair = Keypair.create_from_mnemonic(Keypair.generate_mnemonic(), crypto_type=KeypairType.SR25519)
```