# Are polkascan and subscan same and synced?

Tags: polkadot, polkascan

Are polkascan and subscan.polkadot are same because I'm facing an issue that I've generated an address for polkadot by using python and I've pasted the same address on both of these explorers polkascan shows me the details of address but on subscan.polkadot it throws an error that Account not found

Comment: Can you share the address or screenshots? It can be helpful to see why subscan.polkadot throws the error

Comment: Could you select an answer if any one of them answers your question?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this question comes from [How we can Create Wallet / Generate address in polkadot](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4550/how-we-can-create-wallet-generate-address-in-polkadot).

---

Your gen-account script is purely an offline tool. When you create an address locally. There is no record of this address anywhere, even on the chain. The account won't exist in the actual chain storage until you fund it.

Imagine, there are so many possibilities/accounts in the world. It's impossible for Polkadot to put all of them in storage before the users activate/fund them.

Only when [`NewAccount`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/4b7911607b48a5ca7ebf1d655f12d91cdd241866/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L515-L516) event is deposited, then we could say the account exists now.

---

For Polkascan, it will show an empty(default) `AccountDataInfo`.

For Subscan, it will show not found. I'm pretty sure about this. (I'm a member of Itering/Darwinia/Subscan)